# connect mysql container only works over the IP

Tags: linux, docker, networking

I tried to update my Xibo docker installation. It fails and now it even fails to rollback with the same error. but may it's not so difficult to solve this.

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                                                  NAMES
f6bdba11b113   ghcr.io/xibosignage/xibo-cms:release-2.3.17   "/entrypoint.sh"         About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, :::8080->80/tcp                  xibo_cms-web_1
0c3d431c7cb1   ianw/quickchart                               "node --max-http-hea…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   3400/tcp                                               xibo_cms-quickchart_1
4d310d39fee0   xibosignage/xibo-xmr:release-0.8              "/entrypoint.sh"         About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:9505->9505/tcp, :::9505->9505/tcp, 50001/tcp   xibo_cms-xmr_1
4dc805dcd11b   mysql:5.7
```

Xibo use two main container here in the list: "xibo_cms-web_1" and "xibo_cms-db_1"

The web container has a problem to connect the mysql container. the error message is:

```
docker-compose logs cms-web
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql' (-2)
```

so I call a bash inside the web and try to connect via mysql client. That fails:

```
bash-5.0# mysql  -u cms -p
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql' (-2)
```

but when I use the local IP it works

```
bash-5.0# mysql -h 172.18.0.2 -u cms -p
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 6
Server version: 5.7.37 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MySQL [(none)]>
```

My question: how can I resolve the name 'mysql' in this container?

There must be somewhere the possibility to do this, since it works before I update the container. But how?

The resolv.conf in the web container

```
bash-5.0# cat  /etc/resolv.conf 
search mylocaldomain
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0

bash-5.0# nslookup mysql
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11:53

** server can't find mysql.mylocaldomain: NXDOMAIN

** server can't find mysql.mylocaldomain: NXDOMAIN
```

Edit:
Well, it seems I run in this issue: https://docs.docker.com/network/links/
the docker-compose.yml:

```
links:
    - cms-db:mysql
    - cms-xmr:50001
```

Insinde the web Container I can ping cms-db but not mysql

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem here was (maybe) a [Deprecated](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) docker parameter in the Xibo docker-compose file. But for unknown reason my local docker test enviroment works, the one on the server not. both are same docker versions (Docker version 25.0.1, build 29cf629 on Debian).

I could solve the problem after I add a network alias to the cms-db service in the docker-compose.yml file. The whole part looks now like this

```
cms-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
        - "./shared/db:/var/lib/mysql:Z"
    environment:
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=cms
        - MYSQL_USER=cms
        - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes
    mem_limit: 1g
    env_file: config.env
    restart: always
    networks:
       default:
         aliases:
            - mysql
```